# How to marshal object with array of objects?

Tags: c#, marshalling, sizeof

I have problems with marshaling.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Book
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1000)]
        public Page[] astInject2;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Page
    {
        public int n;
    }
```

Why calling **Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Book))** throws an ArgumentException:

```
Type 'Book' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no  meaningful size or offset can be computed.
```

?

Is there any solution?

I'm marshalling Book object to C++ struct.

If I do this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct Book
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1000)]
        public Page[] astInject2;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct Page
    {
        public int n;
    }
```

then `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Book))` returns 4000 as it should.
Note that I can't define Book as struct, it has to be class.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller doesn't permit exposing pointers to arrays.  Way too many very nasty failure modes with the pinvoked function altering or copying the pointer, no way that can come to a good end.  You can get it by marshaling yourself, declare the field as an IntPtr and assign it from GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() for the array.  Your program will crash in a very nasty way when the function does copy that pointer and the garbage collector moves the array.

Comment: I found an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883308/marshalling-array-of-structs-vs-classes